# Android's IabHelper does not reconnect to the service on disconnected and lead to crashes

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billing

Recently i've got few crashes reported by Crashlytics with the following stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.Bundle com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService.a(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
       at com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:822)
       at com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:526)
       at com.android.vending.billing.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:505)
```

Proguard mapping is:

```
com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService -> com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService:
    int isBillingSupported(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> a
    android.os.Bundle getSkuDetails(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle) -> a
    android.os.Bundle getBuyIntent(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> a
    android.os.Bundle getPurchases(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> a
    int consumePurchase(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) -> b
```

so the crash was [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java#L945):

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                itemType, continueToken);
```

mService was `null`.
I've jumped into service connection and found `IabHelper` [does not](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util/IabHelper.java#L227) try to reconnect to the service:

```
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            logDebug("Billing service disconnected.");
            mService = null;

            // should not it try to rebind to the service here?
        }
```

It means once the service is disconnected all the other invocations lead to app crash like my crash! Is this behavior reasonable? Should not it try to rebind to the service by default? I'd like it to rebind on disconnected to continue working or fire some callback to disable in-app-billing for the user. Any thoughts/better ideas?

Comment: Did you use in your proguard config `-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**`?

Comment: @4ntoine Did you find a solution to this? I have been facing the same issue in my production.